# Stuck with unknown column in field MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I keep getting this error

> Unknown column 'Hello' in 'field list'

when I execute this code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO installs (date,addedBy,customer,reg,vehMake,vehModel,colour,mileage,location,tracker,serial,sim,extr    as,satnav,input1,input2,output,comments) VALUES (" . $date . ", " . $addedBy . ", " . $customer . ", " . $reg . ", " . $vehMake . ", " . $vehModel . ", " . $colour . ", " . $mileage . ", " . $location . ", " . $tracker . ", " . $serial . ", " . $sim . ", " . $extras . ", " . $satnav . ", " . $input1 . ", " . $input2 . ", " . $output . ", " . $comments . ")";
$result = $connect->query($sql) or die($connect->error);
```

Comment: Any reason for all those dots?And why insert a string into a date field?

Comment: Investigate the actual SQL statement that's being executed. Possibly there's something wrong there.

Comment: the lots of dots could be replaced with an `implode(',' ['Hello', 2, 3, 4, ...]);`

Comment: Just use prepared statement. It will both resolve your issue and protect your code from injections when you substitute those values between the dots with variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
  (' . "Hello" . ', ' . 2 . ', ' . 3 . ', ' . 4 . ', ' . 4 . ', ' . 5 . ', ' . 6 . ', ' . 7 . ', ' . 8 . ', ' . 9 . ', ' . 10 . ', ' . 11 . ', ' . 12 . ', ' . 13 . ', ' . 14 . ', ' . 15 . ', ' . 16 . ', ' . 17 . ')';
```

by

```
  ("Hello", 2 ,3, 4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, 13,14,15,16,17)';
```

EDIT:

replace this

```
  (" . $date . ", " . $addedBy . ",..........
```

by

```
  ('$date', '$addedBy',...........
```

or this

```
  ('" . $date . "', '" . $addedBy . "',..........
```

Comment: I've updated the original question, your solution did help with the temp one but doesn't for my new one. Can you check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Hello needs to be enclosed in single quotes. Escape the quotes like this:

```
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO installs 
(date,addedBy,customer,reg,vehMake,vehModel,colour,
    mileage,location,tracker,serial,sim,extras,satnav,
    input1,input2,output,comments)
    VALUES
        (\'' . "Hello" . '\', ' . 2 . ', ' . 3 . ', ' . 4 . ', ' . 4 . ', 
    ' . 5 . ', ' . 6 . ', ' . 7 . ', ' . 8 . ', ' . 9 . ', 
    ' . 10 . ', ' . 11 . ', ' . 12 . ', ' . 13 . ', ' . 14 . ', ' . 15 . ',
    ' . 16 . ', ' . 17 . ')';
```

Comment: Actually, MySQL will accept string literals enclosed in either single quotes or double quotes, unless the sql_mode of the session includes/enables `ANSI_QUOTES`.

Comment: @spencer7593 The fact that sql error says unknown column: Hello tells us that the hello is sent in as a column name (not enclosed in quotes, single or double) and not as a string value.

Answer (score 0):

One likely explanation for this behavior is that sql_mode inclues (or enables) `ANSI_QUOTES`.

```
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode
```

If `ANSI_QUOTES` is enabled, then double quotes can't be used around string literals; whatever is between the double quotes  will be interpreted as an identifier (e.g. column name).  If `ANSI_QUOTES` is enabled, then string literals should be enclosed in single quotes.

---

For the love of all that is good and beautiful in this world, just use prepared statements with placeholders, to avoid issues with quotes and to thwart SQL injection vulnerabilities.

e.g.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO installs (date,addedBy,customer, ...) 
        VALUES ( :date, :addedBy, :customer, ...)";
$sth = $connect->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(':date' => $date, ':addedBy' => $addedBy, ':customer' => $customer, ... ));
```